# Реально ли сделать такой фон без подгрузки изображения?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Собственно, сабж. Делаю лендинг, имеется вот такой "участок" с треугольниками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не приходит ничего в голову кроме как подгружать изображение, но и этот вариант не самый лучший (я молчу про лишний запрос к серваку) - на больших экранах изображение обрезается снизу и становится вот [таким](http://prntscr.com/fisu2e).

Как правильно реализовать такой блок?

Comment: можно на `svg` сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    padding-top: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
section:nth-of-type(2):before,
section:nth-of-type(2):after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}
section:nth-of-type(2):before {   
    border-width: 50px 50vw 0 50vw;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;    
}
section:nth-of-type(2):after{    
    border-width: 50px 0 50px 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section>
    <h2>Title</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так.

```css
.tr{
 width: 50%;
 height: 0;
 padding-left: 25%;
 padding-top: 25%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.tr div {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0;
 margin-left:-500px;
 margin-top:-500px;
 
 border-left: 500px solid transparent;
 border-right: 500px solid transparent;
 border-top: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```

```html
<div class = "tr">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Останется только растянуть по ширине блока.

Более подходящие варианты без лишних выкрутасов описаны в [этом ответе.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464041/cascading-divs-with-triangle-bottom-borders)

Comment: что-то не похоже

Comment: @teran, обновил ответ.